# Loop a jquery animate

Tags: jquery, setinterval

I have this code, it runs once and then stops. I want it to run every ten seconds, I know setinterval will loop the code, but for some reason its not working?

```
<script>
   $(document).ready(setInterval(function(){
       $("#club_color1 a").animate({color: '#000000'}, 1000);
       $("#club_color2 a").animate({color: '#000000'}, 1000);
       $("#club_color1 a").animate({color: '#FFFFFF'}, 1000);
       $("#club_color2 a").animate({color: '#FFFFFF'}, 1000);
   }),10000);
</script>
```

Comment: You can't animate colors using plain JQuery. You should use a additional plugin like http://www.bitstorm.org/jquery/color-animation/

Comment: I am and the above code works, however it only runs once.

Comment: Alright; Just to be sure. See my answer below.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the last line needs to be

```
},10000));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use call back function. So that it execute one after another.

```
$(document).ready(setInterval(function(){
   $("#club_color1 a").animate({color: '#000000'}, 1000,function() {
         $("#club_color2 a").animate({color: '#000000'}, 1000,function() {
               $("#club_color1 a").animate({color: '#FFFFFF'}, 1000,function() { 
                   $("#club_color2 a").animate({color: '#FFFFFF'}, 1000);
               });
         });
   });
},1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

I noticed one thing:

You forgot the anonymous function of the `$.ready()` so do this:

```
<script>
   $(document).ready(function()
       setInterval(function(){
           $("#club_color1 a").animate({color: '#000000'}, 1000);
           $("#club_color2 a").animate({color: '#000000'}, 1000);
           $("#club_color1 a").animate({color: '#FFFFFF'}, 1000);
           $("#club_color2 a").animate({color: '#FFFFFF'}, 1000);
       },10000);
   });
</script>
```

You can make it recursive:

```
$(document.ready(function() { 
   animate(); 
});

function animate() {
   $("#club_color1 a").animate({color: '#000000'}, 1000, animate);
   $("#club_color2 a").animate({color: '#000000'}, 1000, animate);
   $("#club_color1 a").animate({color: '#FFFFFF'}, 1000, animate);
   $("#club_color2 a").animate({color: '#FFFFFF'}, 1000, animate);
}
```

Just add those animations in a function then add that function's name as the last parameter of each `$.animate()` and then call once the `animate()` function when the document's get ready.

Comment: This will eventually throw an error due to infinite recursion

Answer (score 0):

The easiest would be:

```
function doMyAnimations()
{
    $("#club_color1 a").animate({color: '#000000'}, 1000);
    $("#club_color2 a").animate({color: '#000000'}, 1000);
    $("#club_color1 a").animate({color: '#FFFFFF'}, 1000);
    $("#club_color2 a").animate({color: '#FFFFFF'}, 1000);
    setTimeout(doMyAnimations,10000);
}
```

And then call it once on body load:

```
setTimeout(doMyAnimations,10000);
```